# Script_exec() not working when given sh file or command

Tags: php, shell, camera, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run a shell script (starting a raspberry pi camera following the second answer from [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23182/how-to-stream-video-from-raspberry-pi-camera-and-watch-it-live) - `raspivid -o - -t 0 -hf -w 640 -h 360 -fps 25 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554}' :demux=h264`), and I'm executing it from a PHP file. When I try to run the script though, it doesn't work.

Running the script normally either by putting it in an .sh file or just entering the command into the shell both work to turn the camera on. When I put `shell_exec('pwd');` in the PHP file I get the directory back but when I try to run the the camera script either by `shell_exec('[script here]');` or `shell_exec('sh path/to/script.sh');` (or `system([script])` or putting the script in backticks), nothing happens.

I saw that some people had the same problem but the reason was that PHP could not access a specific directory, which is not a problem here since I can run a test script in the same way - it seems as if this is might be a problem with the specific script i'm running, but I can't imagine why, if it runs fine outside of `shell_exec(...);`

Does anyone have any insight as to what might be wrong? Much Thanks!

Comment: Does the web server user have permission to run the script?

Comment: @DavidFindlay I'm fairly sure it does, since I created a test script in the same place that works fine (it just had a `pwd` in it).

Comment: Try su'ing to the web server user then try running the script.

Comment: It works fine as another user. When using sudo to run the script it tells me that 'VLC is not supposed to be run as root. Sorry.
If you need to use real-time priorities and/or privileged TCP ports
you can use /usr/bin/vlc-wrapper (make sure it is Set-UID root and
cannot be run by non-trusted users first).'

Comment: What about if you go "sudo -u www-data myscript.sh"

Comment: looks like the script runs fine when I do it that way =/

Comment: Oops, thought it worked fine but now I'm not sure. The script runs and outputs debugging code to the console but the video doesn't stream. (getting a few errors saying `core playlist warning: could not create /var/www/.local/share/vlc: Permission denied`)  I only see these errors once I stop the streaming with ctrl+c.

Comment: I think that's where you need to look. I've had a few cases where I've spent ages on something that seemed like it should work and turned out to be a permission issue when you run it in the production environment.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update when I fix.